# android-serialport-api reading from serial port

Tags: android, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a serial port in the below given opencv
link, I have no problem with
sending bytes. Everything works fine. There is a problem when i
receive bytes. Every time a read a byte from ttymxc0 something happens
and the byte is not only read for the first time it is sending some
junk data  but after pressing the the two enter keys it is able to
read the data correctly but my concern to read the data without
pressing any enter keys in the beginning only.

http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/checkout

So could any body provide sme corrected code to get rid of this
annoying serial port read problem,

Am new to this android applications development,

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "after pressing the two enter keys". You should post some code snippets from your projects and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

"Android-SerialPort" application works straight forward without any modification, I am not sure what you mean by two key presses required for receiving data. Can you paste code snippet, it is hard to reply to such questions.

Comment: hi its not working for me . I am getting Error: You do not have read/write permission to the serial port. can u help me to resolve this issue